# VPS email - Access to this mail system has been blocked for ip due to spam activity

Tags: email, spam-prevention, vps

I have virtual private server at Godaddy and have around 40 client websites. I usually check the number of emails sent every 3 or 4 days through my Godaddy server management page and saw that around 2000 emails were sent in a single day at the beginning of April. I didn't think too much of it since i had a few clients that have 1000+ subscribers and send weekly bulk emails. But at the end of April, i saw that 3,000 emails were sent per day for 3 days straight and after that my outgoing emails from all domains hosted on my server get a rejection message like this.

***Diagnostic-Code: smtp; 552 5.2.0 yCafawAbxDeCR :DED: Access to this mail system has been blocked for xx.xx.xx.xx due to spam activity. Spam was seen coming from this IP, and possibly other scripts running on it. For help resolving the issue, see http://x.co/spamclean. Once the compromise has been cleaned, please contact customer support to remove the block.***

Obviously the xx.xx.xx.xx is my server's IP and as you can guess, my outgoing emails aren't even delivered. I found the user and i immediately suspended the them and after a day or two, i checked my ip on a lot of websites such as mxtoolbox and spamhaus.org and they say i'm not blacklisted. I even sent a test email to ping@tools.mxtoolbox.com and got the above rejection email.

So here are some of my questions.

1. Where is my IP blacklisted
2. What is the next step to get my IP off the blacklist
3. Do the spamhaus.org and mxtoolbox.com tests actually work
4. Should i rent a new server and move all my websites to that
   one. Would that even help?
5. For the future, is there a way of getting
   a notification when the number of outgoing emails from my server
   reaches a certain number.
6. Is there a way to check which file actually sent the emails. I know there is a way to do that for emails that are currently on queue. Get the message ID and using that ID exim can tell you the actual script that's sending emails. But what about emails that have already been sent and aren't on the mail queue.

Thanks

Comment: Welcome to [su]! Please try and ask 1 question at a time (otherwise your question will be closed as too broad). In addition you are asking for opinions, which is off-topic. 
Please read [How do I ask a good question?](http://superuser.com/help/how-to-ask) and [On-Topic](http://superuser.com/help/on-topic).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. As mentioned in the error, your SMTP service provider is the one blocking you.
2. They tell you to resolve the issue and contact them, which you should do.
3. Yes those check for common black lists, they don't ask all SMTP servers if they block an IP.
4. You should start with the obvious.  Note that if you move after the first incident like that, you'll probably never be in control of the situation, and email sending is a complex task to control.
5. Not if you don't control the SMTP service.
6. Same as the previous question.  You don't have access to your provider's logs.

Answer (score 0):

The thread is a little old, but it can always help someone. After several contacts with the support team without luck, I managed to find the problem.

The server is using EXIM to send mail and it had messages stuck in the queue. This can be seen with the command: `exim -bp`

You can clean the queue using:

`exim -bp | exiqgrep -i | xargs exim -Mrm`